# Tight connection, US domestic to international flight at DTW (Detroit)

Tags: international-travel, layovers, delta-air-lines, air-france, dtw

So im flying to CLT-DTW on delta with ONLY a 52min LAYOVER for my DTW-CDG(Paris) flight,im flying with Air France which is a partner of delta, will i have to go through security again? and i cant find a clear answer as when international flights close the doors cause i know 52min is tight but seeing how they should be in the same concourse im worried but not too worried. either way vert stressful cause i have no idea how international layovers work

Comment: until I know, there is not differences between domestic and international area in US airport. You will need to go thru security only once in US.

Comment: To expand on Marcel's answer.  As we might expect, International arrivals are separated by Immigration and Customs, so you need to clear security again if connecting to a Domestic flight. International and Domestic departures seem connect air-side so no second security is usually needed. However in some cases (eg. EWR A->C) you need to spot an air-side shuttle bus or you can find yourself outside security.

Answer (score 4):

52 minutes should be just enough time for this connection, if your CLT-DTW flight is on time. I spot checked some flights on Flight Aware and the ones I saw almost always arrive 15-20 minutes *early*.

Boarding will close [20 minutes](https://www.airfrance.us/US/en/common/guidevoyageur/aeroport/enregistrement_hle.htm) before departure for your Air France flight. If you're on time, this leaves you 32 minutes to travel at most 1.6 km through the terminal:

Your flights will both arrive and depart from the same terminal, but your gates may be on opposite ends of the terminal. I spot checked some flights on Flight Aware and they seem to have a different gate every day, but always in the [McNamara Terminal](http://www.metroairport.com/Portals/0/9-17-15_Mac_Terminal_Gate_Map.pdf) concourse A. Since the terminal is 1.6km long, you may need to make use of the Express Tram. Or you may find that your departure gate is just a few meters away from your arrival gate.

You will not need to go through security again.